# android back button not working after upgrading to 4.1.1

Tags: android, back-button, mapactivity

I have an android app. The used cases are as below

1. From `activity A` can navigate to `activity B` via `startActivity()` and `activity A` is still on the 'STACK' (A is not finished).
2. Activity B is a subclass of google `MapActivity`
3. On Press of the BACK button , navigation should be from B to A.

The above use case works fine until I upgraded to Android 4.1.1(works fine from 2.3.3 to 4.0.x).

On my current 4.1.1(Samsung S3), the "BACK' button usually not working. When I press the BACK button, the button light up but no action is performed.

I even override the `OnPressBack()` method and placed a Toast message as a flag. But looks like the `OnPressBack()` is not triggered usually. Sometimes it works but most of the time it does not work(go to previous activity A).

And I also found the BACK button issue only happened with the subclass of 'MapActivity'.

Any clue will help. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the new navigation components, you need to make sure the activity that contains your navController overrides the onSupportNavigateUp() function:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
```